# How to make batik start GVT Rendering in the background?

Tags: java, swing, svg, batik

I'm trying to make my application render all SVG images on application start and then show the main frame. When I start my application, it loads several SVG images. Unfortunately, currently it shows the blank frame and then renders images.

I want to substitute:

```
MyCustomFrameWithSVG frame = new MyCustomFrameWithSVG();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

With something like this:

```
MyCustomFrameWithSVG frame = new MyCustomFrameWithSVG();
Renderer renderer = new Renderer(30, frame);

public class Renderer extends GVTTreeRendererAdapter {

    int svgCanvasToLoad;
    MyCustomFrameWithSVG frame;

    public Renderer(int svgCanvasToLoad, MyCustomFrameWithSVG frame) {
        this.svgCanvasToLoad = svgCanvasToLoad;
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void gvtRenderingCompleted(GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
        --svgCanvasToLoad;

        if (svgCanvasToLoad == 0) {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The later code works if I do:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(false);
```

But I don't want to do it on this way.
If I don't show up the frame, the SVG components won't start rendering.

Any ideas how to do it 'properly'?

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: I'm not blocking EDT. I show a splash screen while the app is loading.